# Correlation matrix not including all features in the given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation, feature-extraction

I am having a `DataFrame` of kidney disease symptoms and the `class` column to tell whether a person is a patient or not.
Below is a sample of the dataset given by `df.head(10)`.
[image: df]
Every value in the `df` is either of `int` or `float` datatype, no `str`.

When I applied `df.corr()`, I got the following correlation matrix:-
[image: corr]

It's not including all of the features present in the `DataFrame`. Can you please explain me the reason behind it?
[My complete code is in this git repo](https://github.com/Samar-080301/Chronic-Kidney-Disease)

Comment: Does df.dtypes tell you int or floats? Not sure if you checked that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data looks numeric but the type is still string on many of the columns, do this:

```
x = x.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the wrong information and thanks a lot for your kind help!